# regular functions on distinguished open sets in affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

[image]

I read the algebraic geometry notes of Prof.dr.Andreas Gathmann. In his notes I find the following proposition but fail to understand.
I am confused with the paragraph which is below the equation $g_af_b=g_bf_a$ (*). After obtaining $g_af_b=g_bf_a$, how could I claim they are both zero as claimed in the notes?

Comment: He is not saying they are zero, he is saying they are zero outside of $D(f_a) \cap D(g_a)$